# Prevent URL rewrite from changes underlying links to static files

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I am new to Tuckey's [URLRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), so I am trying this thing.

In my project I got URLS like `index.cfm?action=management.start.home`. I want to rewrite those to `management/start/home`.

So I wrote following filter:

```
<rule>
    <from>/management/start/home</from>
    <to type="redirect">/index.cfm?action=management.start.home</to>
</rule>
```

It works quite well, as the content from given url is shown. But I stumbled upon one problem. all my links to static sources has been changed as well.

All the links got the `management/start/` piece included. EG:

```
public/js/company/jquery.company.button.js
management/start/public/js/company/jquery.company.button.js
```

I can't find the information to fix it at the [Manual](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it changed was that the links were dynamic. So I changed `public/js/company/jquery.company.button.js` to `/public/js/company/jquery.company.button.js` and everything work as expected.